# Rayleigh length determination for Laguerre-Gaussian Modes

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, dispersion

Recently I have measured the [Rayleigh length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_length) of a Gaussian electron beam probe in a scanning electron microscope, using the function:

$$w(z) = w_0 \times \sqrt{1 + (z/z_r)^2}$$

Where $w$ is beam radius, $w_0$ is beam waist, $z$ the displacement from the position of the beam waist (set as the origin) and $z_r$ the Rayleigh length.

What I intend to do next is convert the Gaussian beam into a higher [Laguerre-Gaussian mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam#Laguerre-Gaussian_modes) (a vortex beam) and do the same measurement for Rayleigh length, but what I am unsure of is whether the beam width function above will apply to other beam modes like the one I am about to attempt.

The beam still has a Gaussian envelope, except that there is a phase singularity in the center (giving rise to a "ring" intensity cross-section, as opposed to a spot from a Gaussian beam). I have no reason to believe that it should disperse differently to a Gaussian beam however I can't be sure. Can anyone verify this for me?

I did see another question related to this one mentioning a [Gouy phase shift](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92736/propagating-higher-order-hermite-gauss-modes-using-the-complex-beam-parameter) but again not sure here.